# Issue with PHP and osx 10.7 - runs via command line but not in browser

Tags: php, mac-osx, command-line-interface

I recently removed MAMP as I wanted to have more control over my machine and wanted to make use of PHP5.4 I installed using the script located [here](http://php-osx.liip.ch/) I cannot now not even get my default PHP that is built in to osx to work. I am running this script with a simple  In a document in my ~/Sites directory. I am really at a loss as to why this will not work. I have php5 installed in my /usr/local directory via the link provided above and it seems like the main php is installed in /usr/bin

Any and all insight on how to debug this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like Apache is not properly configured to serve PHP documents. Check /etc/apache2/httpd.conf (or wherever you've stored your Apache config file, if not using the installation that ships with OS X) and make sure you're loading the `mod_php` module.

For example, my config file contains these lines:

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

```
<IfModule php5_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

These may differ slightly based on your Apache installation. You said you "removed MAMP", but then it sounds like you're still using the Apache installation that ships with OS X.

---

You could try adding

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

to a `VirtualHost` configuration block or to a `.htaccess` file and see if PHP works then. If so, Apache is configured properly to use PHP, you just need to associate the `.php` extension with the PHP interpreter.

If it doesn't work, check your error log (probably `/var/log/system.log` on OS X).